# Proper way to move a Bootstrap site to Wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I am looking for a way to move a website built with Bootstrap to Wordpress. I should mention at this point that I know HTML/CSS/Bootstrap (including Gulp) pretty well and am getting more and more comfortable with Wordpress as time goes by, but I don't know much about jQuery or PHP.

It seems that I should not use child themes for something like this, since I want to stick to the original design as much as possible. I was thinking about using some starter theme (such as sage or even underscores/understrap), but is this even possible before I learn jQuery and PHP? On the other hand, I'd rather not use frameworks such as Genesis, as I'm interested in learning a couple of things about how Wordpress themes actually work during the process.

To sum up, can you tell me if it is possible for someone who lacks jQuery/PHP knowledge, to create a Bootstrap theme in Wordpress using underscores/understrap? Also, do you know if there are any other options that I missed while looking into the matter?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Google 'Bootstrap + WordPress' - https://bootstrapwp.com - or check the WP themes for bootstrap to get examples. https://wordpress.org/themes/search/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, definitely possible. WordPress is pretty forgiving and well-documented. JS will be the same as in your bootstrap site.

[Sage](https://github.com/roots/sage) is a fantastic starter theme and does already include bootstrap, but it may not be the best choice if this is your first WordPress theme. Sage does things differently and that could potentially be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is basically just a CSS Framework so you just need to make a style.css file for Wordpress with the usual style.css requirements and upload pages as you would normally for Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

It is most definitely possible. I have gone through the Bootstrap to WordPress course by Brad Hussey, and I felt like that was pretty excellent as far as explaining the process of transitioning Bootstrap built HTML pages to WordPress.

Dig into the WordPress Codex if you want to learn more about stuff when making the transition, because they provide examples of how the code should look in the most basic form. It will definitely help.

Understrap seems to be a good way to go, but I don't know much about it. I started out without any sort of starter theme or framework until eventually using Underscores. Then I just turned Underscores into a Boostrap theme. Now I just use the Genesis framework for most websites.

Answer (score 0):

Its an easy task, here are the steps you should follow to covert html to worspress:

1. Download a starter theme like underscore
2. Install and activate the theme in your  wordpress installation
3. Now in your bootstrap template make sure you have all the pages that are used in wordpress like archive page for post listing, single page for single post, page template etc.
4. Separate header and footer, now replace the header and footer of wordpress with template files. Now make all the static content to dynamic by replacing it with wordpress functions.
5. Add all stylesheets and javascript file from functions.php file
6. Now replace the content of all other templates the same way. Just replace the html content not the php one.
7. You can also modify the nav menu. By adding a class